# Set Kubernetes env variable from container's image version

Tags: kubernetes

I was wondering if it's possible to refer to image field in Kubernetes deployment yaml file,
as

```yaml
    env:
    - name: VERSION
      value:
        valueFrom:
          containerField: spec.image
```

Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu  my app has an endpoint /version it reads from env_var VERSION.

Comment: It supports `metadata.name, metadata.namespace, metadata.labels, metadata.annotations, spec.nodeName, spec.serviceAccountName, status.hostIP, status.podIP, status.podIPs`. Maybe you can add label to the deployment with image version(labels can be passed as env variables) and then pass it to pod?

Comment: I think that's the only way. or maybe in CI process I can expose env_var VERSION, and refer to in yaml. 
Like this: 

`env:
    - name: VERSION
      value: $VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

`image` value in pod definition cannot be passed as environment variable using `fieldRef`.

The only [supported values are](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) `metadata.name, metadata.namespace, metadata.labels, metadata.annotations, spec.nodeName, spec.serviceAccountName, status.hostIP, status.podIP, status.podIPs` and `resource` fields (memory, cpu request/limits) and container ephemeral storage limit/request.

As a workaround it can be passed using labels and then passing this label as an environment variable, example:

```
    env:
    - name: VERSION
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef: 
          fieldPath: metadata.labels['version']
```